# Insert values into a string without using sprintf or to_string

Tags: c++, string-formatting

Currently I only know of two methods to insert values into a C++ string or C string.

The first method I know of is to use `std::sprintf()` and a C-string buffer (char array).

The second method is to use something like `"value of i: " + to_string(value) + "\n"`.

However, the first one needs the creation of a buffer, which leads to more code if you just want to pass a string to a function. The second one produces long lines of code, where a string gets interrupted every time a value is inserted, which makes the code harder to read.

From Python I know the `format()` function, which is used like this:

`"Value of i: {}\n".format(i)`

The braces are replaced by the value in format, and further `.format()`'s can be appended.

I really like Python's approach on this, because the string stays readable, and no extra buffer needs to be created. Is there any similar way of doing this in C++?

Comment: [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/format/)?

Answer (score 5):

Idiomatic way of formatting data in C++ is with output streams ([`std::ostream` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ostream)). If you want the formatted output to end up in a `std::string`, use an [output string stream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
ostringstream res;
res << "Value of i: " << i << "\n";
```

Use `str()` member function to harvest the resultant string:

```
std::string s = res.str();
```

This matches the approach of formatting data for output:

```
cout << "Value of i: " << i << "\n";
```

Comment: +1, but formatting strings with output streams is a far cry from dealing python strings.

Comment: I agree with Pradhan... Even though this seems a better approach than `sprintf`, you simply "replace" the buffer with a stream.